# Jquery DatePicker alter color day from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am wanting to put a jQuery DatePicker that when loaded the month, check the days of the month if there is any record in the database, and if exisitir day as red paint and if there the day with green paint.

I searched and found nothing ... Is it possible to do this? How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJPat/2/)

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: setExistDays
});
```

Basically before showing the calendar days to the user, you can make an **ajax call to your database** to get all the dates belonging to that particular month. Then use the returned dates from ajax to decide whether to color the date cells red.

Or you can simply retrieve the entire list of dates from the database and pass that into date-picker, depending on the size of your data.

Comment: tks ... it was exactly what I needed